# Using macro to get concrete type for a scala.Enumeration

Tags: scala, macros, enumeration

I am trying to get the concrete type in a scala macro for a scala.Enumeration.

For example, given

`def applyImpl[T: c.WeakTypeTag](c: whitebox.Context): c.Expr[String] = ???`

Then for

`object Colours extends Enumeration {
  val Red, Amber, Green = Value
}`

I would like the output to be com.package.Colours (or even just Colours).

I have tried multiple things, but all I can get is a handle to the Enumeration#Value class, and from there I cannot see to work backwards into the real type. Is it even available?